# How to append a value to a p and then remove it from an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Here is the code:

```
var bgChange = "Changing background color".split("");

function typeText (sourCe, tarGet) {
    var i = 0;
    function show () {
        if (i < sourCe.length) {
            $(tarGet).append(sourCe[i]);
            sourCe.splice(i, 1);
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
    var tiMer = setInterval(show, 30);
}

$("#button").click(function(){
    typeText(bgChange, "p");
)};
```

Here is what I want to achieve.

I would like the string "Changing background color" to be turned into an array via "split("")" method, and the values in this array will be appended to an HTML paragraph tag with an interval of 30 mili-seconds, which will create a typing animation.

Also, I would like the array values that have already been appended to be removed from the array so that if I ever stop and resume the typing animation, I would like the animation to resume from where it stopped, which is my intention for putting "sourCe.splice(i, 1)" inside the function.

However, running the function "typeText" by clicking "#button" only appends following characters: "Cagn akrudclr".

I am completely lost as to what is causing this issue.

Comment: its `.split(" ");` not `.split("");`

Comment: @dvenkatsagar I see your point. However, I would like each letter in the string to be separated for the purpose of typing animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are removing the element from array, you just need to read first character from array and append it to `paragraph` element.

Additionally there is a syntax error while closing event handler.

```js
var bgChange = "Changing background color".split("");

function typeText (sourCe, tarGet) {
    function show () {
        if (sourCe.length) {
            $(tarGet).append(sourCe[0]);
            sourCe.splice(0, 1);
        }
    }
    var tiMer = setInterval(show, 30);
}

$("#button").click(function(){
    typeText(bgChange, "p");
});  //Error here
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">button</button>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `splice()`, use `shift()` and also update the logic:

```
function typeText (sourCe, tarGet) {
    function show () {
        if (sourCe.length != 0) {
            $(tarGet).append(sourCe[0]);
            sourCe.shift();
        }
    }
    var tiMer = setInterval(show, 30);
}
```

Comment: It's wrong. The author doesn't want to put whole words in, instead he wants letters. Also - shift and splice(0,1) are identical.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `.split("")` to `.split(" ")` .

There's an issue in your `click-function`:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    typeText(bgChange, "p");
)};
```

Should be

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    typeText(bgChange, "p");
});
```

Also, you maybe want to use this library:

https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/